What is the origin and speciality of Aditi's Earrings and Varuna's umbrella?
In the pastime where Krishna killed bhaumasura we hear about Aditi's Earrings and Varuna's Umbrella. I am looking for their origin, importance and why they are so dear to them? Some big demon does not takes earrings if they are ordinary.
Please provide references.
